# Reading a single disk from RAID1 set (Intel Matrix)

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have an Intel RAID (ICHxR), where a RAID1 set has a failed disk. The problem is that the RAID volume is inaccessible, even though there's one healthy drive still in it. I tried removing the failed disk (which was the first disk in the set), but still no joy. This is what the Intel Matrix Storage Console says:

[image]

When right clicking the drive, there's no "Reset drive to non RAID" option. Right clicking the volume only gives me the option to delete it:

[image]

In Windows disk manager, the disk shows up as uninitialized, which I find an extremely bad sign (Disk 1 in the screenshot):

[image]

Is there any way I can read the disk, or is all hope lost?

Comment: I was going to recommend looking into RAID Reconstructor, but it specifically notes RAID 0 and 5. Do you have an additional drive that you can add in? I'd add it and (if it's not immediately grabbed), set it as a hot spare to trigger a rebuild onto it. You can also try booting a Linux live CD and see if it'll see that as containing any partitions. Don't do ANYTHING destructive, there's also software for examining drives and rebuilding partition tables. Your worst case here is most likely annoyance & time, not actual hard data loss.

Comment: The failed disk had a lucid moment lasting for about an hour, so I managed to save the important files.

Comment: You should be able to connect the good drive to another PC using a usb adapter to read and copy the contents. I have done it recently with one on my mirror drives without issue.